# python docx remove space between text and image?

Tags: python, python-docx

I think picture will explain everything...

```
    paragraph3 = doc.add_paragraph(
        text_dict["title_before_graph1"][0],
        style=style_object["competence_" + text_dict["title_before_graph1"][1]],
    )
    paragraph3.alignment = WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.JUSTIFY

    doc.add_picture("results/section3/competence_1.png", width=Inches(6.25))
```

[image: Amazing right?] 
When I manually remove the empty line after `Georgian school` the picture jumps to previous page and it looks wonderful, what should I do? How to remove that empty line?

Comment: What is `print(f'{text_dict["title_before_graph1"][0]!r}')`?

Comment: Hmm it actually removes the last empty line, although it displays `\n`s all over. Is there a way to make it work partially? haha

Comment: Would you please add your answer outside comment section? I can mark it as solution

Comment: Glad that helped. I'll make an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if there are newline characters terminating your paragraph text by printing it in a rawstring format.

```py
print(f'{text_dict["title_before_graph1"][0]!r}')
```

If you find them at the end of the text, strip them.

```py
    paragraph_text = text_dict["title_before_graph1"][0]
    paragraph_text = paragraph_text.rstrip()
    paragraph3 = doc.add_paragraph(
        paragraph_text,
        style=style_object["competence_" + text_dict["title_before_graph1"][1]],
    )
```